# What is a qualified IRA distribution for a first time home purchase?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, first-time-home-buyer

My wife and I recently purchased our first home.  In order to partially cover the down payment, I withdrew about $18,000 from my Roth IRA (ie its only in my name).

I know the IRS lets you waive the 10% early distribution fee if you are using the funds for a first time home purchase and permits you to withdraw up to $10,000 per individual.  They specifically say that you and your spouse can each withdraw $10,000 and combine the two for a total of $20,000.

My question is, is it okay if my wife and I are both withdrawing from my IRA for our first home purchase or is obtaining $20,000 only permitted if I had an IRA and withdrew $10,000 and she had a separate IRA and withdrew $10,000?

Comment: Have you contributed at least $18,000 to your Roth IRA?  If so, you don't need to worry about the "first-time homebuyer" provision; you can take money out of a Roth penalty-free up to the amount that you have put in at anytime.

Comment: Ben, I have not contributed $18k.  That withdrawal includes interest/capital gains acrued over time.  The account however has been open for over 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

Roth IRA rules are covered under [IRS Publication 590-B](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b/).  Let's look at the text for the [First home exception](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink1000230922):

> **First home.**   Even if you are under age 59½, you do not have to pay the 10% additional tax on up to $10,000 of distributions you receive to buy, build, or rebuild a first home. To qualify for treatment as a first-time homebuyer distribution, the distribution must meet all the following requirements.
>
> 1. It must be used to pay [qualified acquisition costs](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink1000230924) (defined next) before the close of the 120th day after the day you received it.
> 2. It must be used to pay qualified acquisition costs for the main home of a [first-time homebuyer](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink1000230925) (defined below) who is any of the following.
>
>    - Yourself.
>    - Your spouse.
>    - Your or your spouse's child.
>    - Your or your spouse's grandchild.
>    - Your or your spouse's parent or other ancestor.
> 3. When added to all your prior qualified first-time homebuyer distributions, if any, total qualifying distributions cannot be more than $10,000.

This $10,000 amount is a lifetime limit for each taxpayer's IRA accounts.  Therefore, you could take out $10,000 from your IRA, and your wife could take out $10,000 from *her* IRA, but you cannot take out $20,000 from your IRA, because it would exceed your lifetime limits.  The limit is on your account, not on you as a homebuyer.  The reason that "spouse" is listed is that you could take out $10,000 from your IRA to help your spouse buy a house, but this would, again, take up the $10,000 lifetime limit.

That having been said, the Roth IRA is unique among retirement vehicles in that you are allowed to take out any amount that you have contributed, penalty-free, for any reason at any time.  Therefore, if your total contributions into your Roth IRA has been at least $8,000, then you can count $8,000 as a return of your contributions, and another $10,000 as a qualified distribution under the first-time homebuyer provision to avoid the penalty.

Comment: Ben, nice point that the early distribution only applies to amounts beyond the contributions.  I had not fully considered that.  I also get your point on the lifetime limit.  I had read the IRS publication already but the verbiage did not entirely make sense until you just explained it so thank you.